# Unwrapping a text box widget of tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having an issue with unwrapping the text box widget in tkinter

```
    self.usrText1 = Text(self.usrDetailsFrame, height=4, width=15)
    self.usrText1.insert(END, "Enter Text")
    self.usrText1.grid(row=8, column=1, sticky=W, padx=3)
```

Now when i try to update the text box with a string with multiple lines, i get a wrapped version of the string, which causes distortion of the very well formatted string from `"\n".join(self.person.getBooks())`

```
    self.usrText1.delete("1.0",END)
    self.usrText1.insert(END,"\n".join(self.person.getBooks()))
```

How do i unwrap the text box? Or add scrollbars maybe? Please note that i am using python 2.7, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the documented `wrap` option for the text widget:

```
self.usrText1 = Text(..., wrap="none")
```

Comment: oh i didnt know you could do that! Thanks